# pip install or upgrade fails with - free(): invalid pointer Aborted

Tags: package-management, upgrade, software-installation, python, pip

I get this error when trying to upgrade pip, pip3 or when I try to install a python package. What can I do?

root$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (21.0.1)
Collecting pip
Using cached pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted

I tried moving .cache so far and run this command as another user as well. Didn't help.

Edit:
I'm using the following Ubuntu version

root$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using it could matter.

Comment: I just edited my initial question with the information. It is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS